# how to get customized alert dialog , like the one shown in image?

Tags: android

[image: want to have alert dialog like this]i want to build a customized dialog just like the one shown in image:

i have created two layout one for custom title & other containing two edit text view along with two buttons.Here are xml's

custom_title

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/popup_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/addView"
        android:textColor="@color/black" 

        android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/title"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/details"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_add" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_cancel" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: unable to get white background of alert dialog somme blue color also appearing

Comment: alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setCustomTitle(view1);alert.setView(layout);
    //alert.set
    alert.create();
    alert.show();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to inflate the Dialog with your xml file.
I'll just give you a sample code, then you can easily follow

```
private View mView;
private Dialog mDialog;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
```

Now create a function as  :-

```
private void showCustomDialog() {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(
            LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ContextThemeWrapper mTheme = new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
            R.style.YOUR_STYE);

    mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_XML_LAYOUT_FILE, null);
    // mDialog = new Dialog(this,0); // context, theme

    mDialog = new Dialog(mTheme);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setContentView(this.mView);
    mDialog.show();

    TextViiew someText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
    // do some thing with the text view or any other view 

}
```

Finally make sure you have the style as :-

```
<style name="YOUR_STYLE">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

That's it .... you are done... just call this function where ever you want to show the custom dialog....

Hope the explanation was useful....

Comment: layout is not dispalyed on full dialog , black background also appearing

Comment: can you explain it properly... i mean whats happening or probably upload a pic of what you are getting...

Comment: also just try out this one 

mDialog = new Dialog(this,0); // context, theme

and DON'T use the Custom Theme Wrapper.... comment both the lines

Comment: here is url of image(dialog) that i am getting :http://tinypic.com/r/33tteko/6 . Want to get rid of black background & grey strip at the title (my custom title layout not taking covering whole width).

Comment: Are you using the above XML or you have changed it 

just send me your latest XML file

Comment: Also why are you using 2 different XML files... you can do the entire thing in one XML file....

Comment: there is no change in xml , using xml's that are posted above.Thnks for concern

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17551/discussion-between-vaibvorld-and-aamir-shah)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) tutorial, it might be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the like here one example that use custom AlertDialog. it help you.

Check the [link](http://deadmango.com/index.php/archives/1025)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:text="Add Your View" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Title" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Details" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Add" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="Cancel" />
```

it is the code u need